# Your script, Monthly stats for Gmail, has recently failed mail

Tags: google-apps-script

Your script, Monthly stats for Gmail, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

But when I click the link https://script.google.com/macros/triggers?id=Ms_-wD1MUH3Gn7nts7-nrN-VJ5jnXUK_T   I get a error 403

I have never made any script in my google docs, so I have no idea why I get that mail

Comment: If this is a bug, you can report it on the Issue Tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)

Comment: Sounds like you have installed an add-on or library that executes as you and sends notifications emails. You can revoke access to scripts by visiting your Google account's permissions page: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions